# How to create custom brew bottle

Tags: homebrew

I have a go application that I would like to distribute for a few developers. Is it possible with "bottles & taps"?

I have tried:

```
brew tap-new <name of tap>
```

This gives me a local repository:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in <local path>
```

I possible what to do then, I can't find any documentation for custom bottle?

Answer (score 2):

It's vaguely documented [right over here](https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles#root-url-root_url); your formula would probably define

```
bottle do
  root_url "https://my-internal-server/"
  sha256 "..." => :sierra
  sha256 "..." => :el_capitan
  sha256 "..." => :yosemite
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I then push this vaguely doc. to github together with the binary - to be able to do brew install <tool nam> after adding brew tab <url to github>?

Comment: Like any custom tap, you should then be able to do `brew tap ...` and `brew install` (or directly `brew install yourgithubusername/yourgithubrepo/formulaname`) and if there is a bottle available for your platform, it should get used.